# How to get specific string/value from an array? php

Tags: plugins, php, functions, ajax, javascript

I am creating a custom wordpress theme and i am little stuck in one situation. I created an array $ark and get some values in it

```
<?php  $ark[] = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'pdff', $post->ID ) );  print_r($ark) ; echo 'jonty'; ?>
```

here below  is the output of the above code;

```
Array ( [0] => /jobifylocal/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?pdff=127 ) jonty
```

what i want is that the only value of pdff after equals-to like here 127 i only need 127 in a $variable to echo somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to get the 'pdff' value:

```
$url_components = parse_url($ark[0]); 

// Use parse_str() function to parse the 
// string passed via URL 
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 
      
// Display result 
echo $params['pdff'];
```